ESP32-S3 saving variables in flash memory using preferences.h library
I am working on an indoorlocalization unit for my thesis. I need to store measured data in an array in the flash memory, as i will do the measuring over a couple of days, and will need the stored data in the next phase of my project. It worked fine until after roughly 40 measures (i will do 250) no wont it store any new values. I first though that the problem was with the refrencing when storing the values. but i have tried to overwrite an old measurement many, which i have done many times before. And it does not work. It feels as the saving part of my code has just freezed. It should not be a memory issue, because the whole matrix is already saved, I am just trying to overwrite the default values for each element. The project contains many custom libraries that i have written. I will therefor link the github repo which contains the whole project.
Thanks in advance!
https://github.com/ChrisKheder/IndoorLocalizationUnit
I have tried to reduce the size of the matrix as i thought it was a memory problem, did not help. i also implemented to only the interested row i being saved when calling the save function, instead of saving the whole RSSI matrix. I tried measuring a point which i managed to save a value before, does not work anymore.
